# Git rebase vs recreating branch and applying changes

Tags: git, github, rebase

I have to rebase and then, squash and merge my changes. But, the rebasing is taking too much time and effort. So, what if, instead of rebasing, I delete the feature branch, create a fresh one from master and then, apply my changes at the top and push in a single commit?

1. Will it be any different than rebasing?
2. Will the git(hub) review comments be preserved?

Comment: 1) Technically, the result is the same while you chose a very hard way. No need to delete the feature branch at all (why otherwise?). Try using `git rebase -i master feature` using the `s`/`squash` command and making up a nice commit message (I do believe squashing is usually bad). 2) I don't use GitHub for that, but I guess GitHub comments have nothing to do to this operation. The PR and its contents will most likely remain preserved in any case unless the PR is deleted. In GitLab I use even deleting a remote branch simply closes the associated MR (merge request, PR in terms of GitLab).

Answer (score 1):

From a technical standpoint, the end result is the same. Rebase is just a smart tool to do exactly what you describe.

I've resorted to manual editing a few times in the past, but generally it pays off to get proficient at using interactive rebase using Vim or Emacs.

`rebase -i` seems arcane at first, especially as the default text editor is often Vim; however, the two go very well together: if you want to reorder commits, you just hit `j` until you get to the commit you want to move `dd` to delete the line then `j` again (or `k` to go up) until you find the place you want to put it, then `p` to paste it.

Or, say you want to squash a three commits into one, use `jjj` (or `3j`) to get to the line you want, then use `cw` (change word) `s` ("squash" (see instructions at top of text file)) <kbd>`Esc`</kbd> `j` `.`

Where Esc leaves insert mode and returns to "normal" mode and `.` repeats the last command.

Comment: And—handy command while you're getting used to vim—`:e!` followed by enter or return key (however it's labeled on your keyboard) will re-load an unsaved file. So if you goof up the rebase instruction sheet and have not written it out yet, you can use `:e!` to start over. When you're done, use `:x` (and return/enter) or `ZZ` (no enter-key required) to save-and-exit.